# Android, center image on a specific point

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an image that I am placing inside of a FrameLayout inside my top level RelativeLayout. I need this image to be centered a bit above the center of the FrameLayout, but I am having a hard time finding info on how to do this. I can provide any other info as needed and I'm open to doing this another way if there is a better one. Thanks

Comment: Post your xml code so we can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of these attributes to push your `ImageView` up slightly from the center of your `FrameLayout`

```
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Here is a full example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ccc"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which will appear as such:

[image]